# grep -l 'string' path prints the path followed by 'is a directory'

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to get grep to return the string matches in files in a directory, but instead it is just returning the path followed by 'is a directory'. I looked in the man pages and did grep --help, but I do not understand the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `-r` for recursive.

The following will search through `some_directory` looking for files that contain `something`:

```
grep -l -r something some_directory
```

If you don't specify `-r`, `grep` thinks that you are trying to search the directory itself and it appropriately responds:

```
grep: some_directory: Is a directory
```

With `-r`, `grep` understands that you want to look for files in the directory tree starting with `some_directory`.

#### To retrieve file names without paths

To remove the paths from the file names, we can, for example, use `basename`:

```
grep --null -l -r something some_directory | xargs -0 -n1 basename
```

If you just want to eliminate `some_directory` while keeping any subdirectories, then use:

```
( cd some_directory; grep -l -r something . )
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Additionally, how do I make it print just the filenames and not the whole path?

Comment: @Egbert `grep` won't do that on its own but we can use `basename` to do that.  See updated answer.